# Necessity of synchronized on local variable

Tags: java, synchronized

In the JSON-java library ([org.json.JSONArray](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONArray.java)) I have found this code snippet with a `synchronized` block around a method-local variable

```
public String toString(int indentFactor) throws JSONException {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    synchronized (sw.getBuffer()) {
        return this.write(sw, indentFactor, 0).toString();
    }
}
```

I do not understand the necessity for the synchronization here, as the `StringWriter` is only local to the given method (and, why the synchronization is on the Buffer). Is the synchronization really necessary here, and if, why?

Comment: It is unnecessary. With the default constructor, the buffer is a newly instantiated object. `buf = new StringBuffer();` inside the constructor.

Comment: Note that the author of the org.json library is a JavaScript programmer, not a Java programmer, and this fact is demonstrated throughout the code. For serious JSON processing, consider using Google's Gson library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be a performance optimization.  In the oracle jvm, re-acquiring an already held lock is very fast.  Presumably, the `write` call is making numerous calls into the StringBuffer.  By locking before calling `write`, the lock will be held through all of those calls instead of being released and re-acquired for each call.

Comment: As of Java 6, lock biasing means that acquiring an uncontended lock is fast anyway.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - yes, i don't know how relevant that particular performance optimization still is (or ever was).

Comment: I don't understated _being released and re-acquired for each call_. The `write()` call doesn't try and `synchronize` on the `Writer` at all. The lock gets acquired and released only once, inside the `toString(int)` method in OP's question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - all the methods of StringBuffer (which underlies the StringWriter) are synchronised.

Answer (score 6):

The empty constructor for `StringWriter` is

```
/**
 * Create a new string writer using the default initial string-buffer
 * size.
 */
public StringWriter() {
    buf = new StringBuffer();
    lock = buf;
}
```

Nothing is shared, therefore the `synchronized` block is unnecessary.

Unless... `write` delegates to another thread, but I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

`getBuffer()` returns a `StringBuffer`, and according to the documentation a `StringBuffer` is already synchronized:

> String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The methods are synchronized where necessary so that all the operations on any particular instance behave as if they occur in some serial order that is consistent with the order of the method calls made by each of the individual threads involved.

This means that synchronizing again on the `StringBuffer` is totally overkill. Changes to the `StringWriter` will automatically be synchronized because it uses the synchronized `StringBuffer` internally.

Since the `StringWriter` instance is local to the method call, it's impossible to have multiple threads accessing the same instance at the same time, which also makes synchronization unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.
Every thread creates its own local variable in the method and synchronizes on it.Each time entering the method threads create their own object-monitor which cannot be held by another thread because it's local and lives only on thread's stack!