# Can you call synchronized on a method variable?

Tags: java, multithreading

**This honestly compiles and runs in Java 7**

Just what the question says - while it is technically legal to do so, if you call synchronized on some method variable, does it actually achieve anything? Or is it, because method variables exist within their own little world, going to fail to achieve anything worthwhile?

eg:

```
public int getX(){
    Integer k = 12;
    synchronized (k) {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: "_while it is technically legal to do so_". Nope; it is not. See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Comment: What do yuo mean by "method variable" a local object created inside method or an object passed as parameter to the method?

Comment: @BoristheSpider i don't know about you, but I can literally write code that does it - as in the edited question - that does that and it compiles and runs fine. I'm using Java 7 on my machine right now though (because of requirements from other software I use).

Comment: @bharal that's not "_call[ing] synchronized on some method variable_", it's a [`synchronized` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19). It does what the JLS says it does - provides synchronized access to the block with the variable instance in question as the lock.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sure, whatever. You're not answering the question though - maybe my question is insane, or you don't understand the question? Also referring to *the entire JLS* isn't a very useful thing to do, regarding your first comment!

Comment: @bharal I linked to the [specific section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306513/can-you-call-synchronized-on-a-method-variable?noredirect=1#comment69816176_41306513) when you clarified your question.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh! I didn't hit that last link. And it still doesn't answer my question. And your first comment is still wrong because it is technically legal.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking the wrong question. Whether the *variable* is local is irrelevant, as shown in the following example:

```
class Test {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        Map<String, String> localMap = this.map;
        synchronized (localMap) {
            localMap.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The local reference is actually necessary if there's a possibility that the field could be replaced while you're in the `synchronized` block.

So the real question is whether you should ever lock on a private *value*, that is, an object not available to other threads. You may think your example demonstrates such a case, but per the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7-300), the autoboxed `Integer` `12` is cached, meaning *you're actually synchronizing on a global value*.

Now, assuming you have a local value that's actually private to its thread, there's generally no point in synchronizing on it, and I think some analyzers will warn you if you try. However, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18318203/1553851) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123024/synchronization-on-the-local-variables) for a possible exception.